# GHC says "digits" needs an Int, when it needs an Integral

Tags: haskell, ghc

As far as I can see, this code snippet should compile without a problem:

```
import Data.Digits (digits)
-- |convert integer to arbitrary base with specified charset
-- base/radix is charset string length.
-- eg. convert the integer 255 to hex:
--      intToBaseN 255 "0123456789abcdef" = "ff"
numToBaseN :: Integral n => n -> [Char] -> String
numToBaseN num charlst = map (\i -> charlst !! (fromIntegral i)) lst where
    lst = digits (length charlst) num
```

But GHC complains that the `num` in the `lst` expression isn't an `Int`. But the type of `digits` is

```
digits :: Integral n => n -> n -> [n]
```

it doesn't require an `Int` as an argument, only something that is an Integral, which the type signature of `numToBaseN` does as well.

`!!` requires an Int, which is why it is converted using `fromIntegral`.

What's going on here?

It compiles if I replace `num` with `(fromIntegral num)`, but then I lose the ability to convert an Integer (ie. arbitrarily large integers).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both arguments to `digits` need to have the same type and `length charlst` has the type `Int`, so `num` must also have type `Int`.

> It compiles if I replace num with (fromIntegral num), but then I lose the ability to convert an Integer

If you apply `fromIntegral` to `length charlst` instead, it will convert it to whichever type `num` is, so it'll work the way you want.

Comment: `genericLength` is also an option, but less frequently used probably because it requires another import line.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson `genericLength` is also known to have much poorer performance in general (although rewriting rules at least for `Int` and `Integer` exist.)

Comment: @sepp2k thanks. I guess I had a hard time understanding that fromIntegral converts from both Integer to Int and the other way around too. Plus the GHC error message makes it seem like the last argument is the problem, rather than, perhaps, the first (ie. error is "num not of right type" rather than "type mismatch between first and second argument to digits").